# Flexslider2 shows for a moment all content on initialisation

Tags: jquery, flexslider

When I open my website, my Flexslider 2 shows for a short moment all the content I have in my slider, which in this case are three words, which afterwards fade in one another.

http://jakubdegler.ch/involved/

I have this in my head:

```
   <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>


<!-- FLEXSLIDER -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

  // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
    // start: function(slider) { slider.removeClass('loading');  }



    $(window).load(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade"


      });

    });



 </script>
```

This is my Flexslider HTML:

```
<div class="row" >
<div class="medium-12 large-12 columns" id="nopadding">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="parallax-bg">

      <div class="title">

            <!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
              <div class="flexslider loading">
                <ul class="slides">

                  <li>
                    <p>Menschen</p>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <p>Werte</p>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <p>Fähigkeiten</p>
                  </li>



                </ul>
              </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS try to hide all the elements from the slideshow on the first hand and then show them when you display the slider:

`.slides li p { display: none; }`

And on flexslider init:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "fade",
     start: function() {
       $('.slides li p').show();
     }
   });

 });
```

Also looking at your code I saw you're using three versions of `jquery` in the same page. You should not do that. One is enough. I'm refering to these:

`<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Sorry, it won't show..... console in Chrome says this:
(index):37 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @KubaDegi, sorry I missed a `,` after `animation: "fade"` check my updated answer. The error that I see in the console now states exactly that. Now it should work.